# IFrame Content shows white in IE7 and with IE=EmulateIE7 (Sharepoint)

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I want to embed my web application inside Sharepoint as a web part. This works great on IE8, IE9 and Firefox - but when I open the page with IE7 I can see only a blank (white) IFrame although the inner content has been loaded. The same webapp opened without the Iframe works perfect - also in IE7.

Same for IE8/IE9 with the META tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I also can click with the right mouse button on the white area and can display the source code of the page embedded in the IFrame.

My IFrame is embedded like this:

```
<iframe title="WebApp" frameBorder="0" id="MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2" style="z-index: 1000" name="MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2" width="1200px" 
height="1200px" src="http://webapps/app1/beta.webapp.aspx?ContentAreaHeight=669px" ddf_src="http://webapps/app1/beta.webapp.aspx?ContentAreaHeight=669px"
<div class="UserGeneric">No IFRames supported.</div></iframe>
```

In Sharepoint it makes no difference if I embed the IFrame manually with the Content Editor webpart or with the Page Viewer webpart.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Might be a Sharepoint thing but could you tell me what the `ddf_src` attribute is? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @MattK Sorry, I have no idea what ddf_src is. I removed it and nothing changed...

Comment: if you change the `src` to another site does it work?

Comment: yes it works for other sites - I removed one css style after another from the page in the Iframe and found the cause in html { height: 100% } => after removing that it works again in IE7

Comment: cool. you can also accept your own answer so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed CSS style in IFrame page:

```
html {
  height: 100%; <= removed this line
}
```

... then it worked again